# Ionic select - not able to set a selected value

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have ionic select box and options are populating like below., I want to set the first value of the collection to be selected by default. please help

```
<ion-select interface="popover">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let cps of selectedCP" value="{{cps.ID}}" checked="true" (ionSelect)="selectAssets($event, cps)">{{cps.Name}}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the default value using **`[(ngModel)]`**

```
 <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedP" interface="popover">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let cps of selectedCP" value="{{cps.ID}}" checked="true" (ionSelect)="selectAssets($event, cps)">{{cps.Name}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

and in .TS

```
this.selectedP= selectedCP[0];
```

Comment: try  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedP.ID" interface="popover">